# what is the dimension of $\wedge^k(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let's say $B = \{x_1, x_2, ... x_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $\wedge^k(V)$ has basis $\{x_{i_1} \wedge x_{i_2} \wedge ... \wedge x_{i_k} : i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_k\}$.  I'm not exactly clear on what this basis is.  How many elements does it have and how can these be determined?

Comment: Study its skew-symmetry.

Comment: There should only be $i_1$ upto $i_k$.

Comment: oops, you're right

Answer (score 4):

The basis you describe has one element for each $k$-element subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

There are $\binom nk$ such subsets, so the dimension of $\Lambda^k(V)$ is $\binom{\dim(V)}{k}$.

For example, for $n=4, k=2$, the basis elements would be
$$ \begin{array}{lll} \{\; x_1\wedge x_2, & x_1 \wedge x_3, & x_1 \wedge x_4, 
\\ & x_2 \wedge x_3, & x_2 \wedge x_4,
\\ & & x_3 \wedge x_4 \;\} \end{array} $$

Comment: Thank you, that make sense.  How would linear independence be established in this context?  I feel like the standard method of setting up a matrix and row reducing it will not suffice here.

Comment: @SocraticaFan: Hmm, that depends on exactly how you have _defined_ $\Lambda^k(V)$. If it's by a universal property, I think most straightforward would be to prove that the space of _formal_ linear combinations of these postulated basis elements satisfies the universal property, and therefore this space _is_ $\Lambda^k(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

The basis for $\Lambda^k(V)$ consists of all choices of ascending $k-$tuples of indices contained in $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ where $n=\dim(V)$. This is equivalent to the combinatorial problem of choosing a subset of size $k$ from $\{1,\ldots, n\}$. So, there are
$$ \dim(\Lambda^k(V))={n\choose k}={\dim(V)\choose k}$$
ways to do this.